The Frobenius and Dold–Puppe
At the end of Lecture 12 in the Clausen–Scholze, Lectures on Analytic Geometry, there is a discussion of the exact endofunctor of $D_{\geq 0}(A)$ defined by $Q\mapsto \operatorname{colim}_n \operatorname{Sym}^i(Q[n])[-n]$. This functor vanishes unless $i$ is a prime power so let's assume that $i=p^m$. In that case the functor is supposed to be filtered by copies of the functor $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A}(A/p)$ where the tensor uses the map $A\to A/p$ given by the Frobenius $a\mapsto a^{p^m}$. It is very difficult for me to understand this claim. When I look in Dold–Puppe, I cannot find any place where the Frobenius is discussed. Exactly what filtration is being used here and how precisely do copies of $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A}(A/p)$ get involved? Where can I look to see more details on this? Does something like this appear in some text on the Goodwillie calculus?

I would like to add that I am aware of https://mathoverflow.net/q/424237/3396 and Hyslop's informative answer there, but that still does not explain the connection to the Frobenius that I am looking for.

$\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}$Let's first consider the case $i=p$, and I'll assume for simplicity that $A$ is an ordinary commutative ring flat over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. We will show that the 1st Goodwillie derivative of $\Sym^p$ is the functor $Q\mapsto \mathrm{cone}((Q^{\otimes p})_{hS_p}\to \Sym^p Q)$. I presume that this is classical in homotopy-theoretic literature, but I don't know of a good reference; I learned this way of phrasing Dold-Puppe's computation from Jeremy Hahn, all possible mistakes below are of course mine.
For a flat $A$-module $Q$ there is a natural map $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}\to \Sym^p Q$ from derived coinvariants of the symmetric group to the classical coinvariants. It induces an isomorphism on $H^0$, and all other cohomology modules of $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}$ are either zero, or naturally isomorphic to $Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$. Specifically, $H^{-i}((Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p})$ is this Frobenius twist of $Q/p$ for positive $i$ of the form $2(p-1)k+1$, and is zero in all other degrees.
Let me briefly recall how this computation goes, to see where the Frobenius twist comes from. The natural map $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hC_p}\to (Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}$ from the coinvariants under the cyclic subgroup of order $p$ establishes $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}$ as the direct summand of $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hC_p}$ equal to the invariants under the action of the normalizer of $C_p$ in $S_p$.
But the homology complex $(Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hC_p}$ of $C_p$ acting on $Q^{\otimes_A p}$ can be computed explicitly using the $2$-periodic complex
$$\ldots\xrightarrow{1-\sigma}Q^{\otimes p}\xrightarrow{1+\sigma+\ldots+\sigma^{p-1}}Q^{\otimes p}\xrightarrow{1-\sigma}Q^{\otimes p}$$
where $\sigma$ is a generator of $C_p$. This complex has $H^{-i}=0$ for even positive $i$, and $H^{-i}$ for odd positive $i$ is isomorphic to $Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$ with the isomorphism sending $q\otimes a\in Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$ to the cohomology class of $q^{\otimes p}\cdot \tilde{a}$ for any $\tilde{a}\in A$ lifting $a\in A/p$. Passing to the invariants under the action of the normalizer of $C_p$ in $S_p$ then leaves non-zero cohomology only in degrees congruent to $1$ modulo $2(p-1)$.
Therefore for any $Q\in D_{\geq 0}(A)$ we have a natural fiber sequence $$T(Q)\to (Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}\to \Sym^p Q$$ with $T$ a functor that admits a complete filtration with graded pieces given by shifts of the functor $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$. The first Goodwillie derivative of the functor $Q\mapsto (Q^{\otimes_A p})_{hS_p}$ is zero, because $(Q[n]^{\otimes p})_{hS_p}[-n]$ is concentrated in cohomological degrees $\leq n-pn$, so the colimit over $n$ is zero by degree reasons.
Hence the connecting map $\Sym^p Q\to T(Q)[1]$ in the above fiber sequence induces an equivalence on 1st derivatives, but $T(Q)[1]$ is already an exact functor, because $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$ is exact, so $T(Q)[1]$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{colim}_n \Sym^p(Q[n])[-n]$ and has a filtration with desired properties.
We can now quickly deduce the computation for the functor $\Sym^{p^m}$ using that the natural map $\Sym^p\circ\ldots\circ \Sym^p\to \Sym^{p^m}$ establishes $\Sym^{p^m}$ as a direct summand of the composition of $m$ iterates of $\Sym^p$. Indeed, for a flat $A$-module $Q$ this composition can be identified with coinvariants in $Q^{\otimes p^m}$ under the action of a subgroup of $S_{p^m}$ of order $p!\cdot (p!)^p\cdot\ldots\cdot (p!)^{p^{m-1}}$, so its index is coprime to $p$, and averaging over cosets of this subgroup defines a section of the map $(\Sym^p)^{\circ m}\to\Sym^{p^m}$.
1st derivative of the composition of functors commuting with filtered colimits is the composition of its first derivatives, by Corollary 6.2.1.24 in Higher Algebra https://people.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf . In terms of the description of the derivative of a functor $F$ as the colimit $Q\to \mathrm{colim}_n F(Q[n])[-n]$ we can see this by considering, for two functors $F,G$ the colimit of $F(G(Q[n])[m])[-m-n]$ indexed by pairs of non-negative inegers $m,n$. The natural maps
$$(F\circ G)(X[n])[-n]\to F(G(X[n])[m])[-m-n]\to F(G(Q[n+m]))[-m-n]$$
show that $\mathrm{colim}_{m,n}F(G(Q[n])[m])[-m-n]$ identifies with $\mathrm{colim}_n (F\circ G)(Q[n])[-n]$, but on the other hand this $2$-variable colimit identifies with the composition of derivatives of $F$ and $G$ evaluated on $Q$, using that the derivative of $F$ commutes with filtered colimits.
Hence the derivative of $(\Sym^p)^{\circ m}$ has a complete filtration with graded pieces that are shifts of $m$-fold compositions of the functor $Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^p}A/p$. This composition has a finite filtration with associated graded pieces $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^{p^m}}A/p$. To see that the direct summand $\Sym^{p^m}$ of $(\Sym^p)^{\circ m}$ also gets a filtration with graded pieces given by shifts of $Q\mapsto Q\otimes_{A,a\mapsto a^{p^m}}A/p$ it suffices to note that this functor of $m$-th Frobenius twist has no non-zero endomorphisms other than the identity, that would also be compatible with base change in $A$.

Great, thanks!!

for a slightly different approach, I think the argument for Proposition 2.2.1 in this paper could be modified to prove this claim (just replace the homotopy fixed points with the corresponding derived functor of fixed points, forget about EG, and use the fact that symmetric powers and divided powers are related by a shift): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.00054
